# Telethon events.NewMessage() doesn't work

Tags: python, telethon

I try to catch new messages in 4 certain channels, but not all channels work.
If I write to account from my second account - script works.
If there is new message in some channel - script doesn't see the event at all.

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 11111
api_hash = 'fjnbkdnslkfnbksbs'
client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()


@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handle(event):
    print('I see the message')


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple. I needed to upgrade telethon using
`pip install --upgrade telethon`

Comment: I tried it, but the problem remains. Is it associated with certain Telethon versions?